# JQuery - prevent form submitting on enter button with out prevent the keystrok

Tags: javascript, yii, jquery

JQuery - prevent form submitting on enter button with out prevent the keystroke

```
$('.filters').keypress(function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode === 13) 
    {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('lead-category-grid', {
                   data: $(this).serialize()
            });
       return false;
    }
});
```

since this function will prevent the enter keystroke.
but i need some function to execute but form should not submitted

Comment: you can execute the whatever you want in the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.filters').keypress(function(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode === 13) 
    {
       // .... execute your functions here....
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: if i put jquery function there will it work for me its not working..

Comment: have you tried putting it there?

Comment: i did try using function before `return false;`. but i didn't get answer
the problem is with yii framework. from here
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/22996-avoiding-form-submission-on-enter-in-a-cgridview-filter-field/
i got patch and updated framework now its working.
anyway `@ibu` thanks for your time.